# Run ES6 constructor in Angular 1.5 component

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

I try to run the ES6 constructor code when the 'soran' tag is loaded.
but it just ignores. how can I run certain code by using a controller in angular 1.5 component() ?

```
import { config } from './index.config';
import { routerConfig } from './index.route';
import { runBlock } from './index.run';
import { MainController } from './main/main.controller';

angular.module('soranSpace', ['ngAnimate', 'ngCookies', 'ngSanitize', 'ngMessages', 'ngAria', 'restangular', 'ui.router'])
  .config(config)
  .config(routerConfig)
  .run(runBlock)
  .controller('MainController', MainController)

  .component('soran', {
    bindings: {},
    template: '<div id="map-viewport"></div>',
    scope: {},
    controller: soranController
  });

class soranController {
  constructor($log) {
    'ngInject';

    $log.log("run!");  // how to run this ? 
  }
}
```

Comment: doesn't look like you injected $log to the controller, is there any error in console?

Comment: @sdfacre there is no error in console.

Comment: did you register the controller? .controller('soranController', soranController);

Comment: `controller: soranController` -> `soranController` is undefined at this point. It's hard to believe that you don't get any error.

Answer (score 3):

Move the class definition above the component definition. In ES6, class declarations are not hoisted, so `soranController` is not defined at the time where your component is defined. I ran into this same issue last week, and it didn't throw any error for some reason - I reckon it's something to do with how the code gets transpiled.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Hoisting

Answer (score -3):

You need to write:

```
controller: () => new soranController(),
```

As it expects a function.